# UITextView won't resignFirstResponder so another can becomeFirstResponder

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I have a toolbar in my UITextfields' inputAccessoryView. If the 'next' button is hit it makes the next textfield in an orderedSet of all my textfields become the first responder. THAT works perfectly.

BUT I can't get the 'previous' textfield to becomeFirstResponder.

I've checked in the console and the textfield does call textFieldShouldBeginEditing and I am returning YES but it never calls textFieldDidBeginEditing and the textfield that should resignFirstResponder never calls textFieldShouldEndEditing.

So the textfield is getting the message to becomeFirstResponder but doesn't.

```
- (IBAction)keyboardBarButtonDidTouch:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    if (sender==self.previousBarButton&&self.activeTextFieldArrayIndex.intValue>0)
    {
        [(UITextField *)[self.textfields objectAtIndex:(self.activeTextFieldArrayIndex.intValue-1)] becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if (sender==self.nextBarButton&&self.activeTextFieldArrayIndex.intValue<(self.textfields.count-1))
    {
        [(UITextField *)[self.textfields objectAtIndex:(self.activeTextFieldArrayIndex.intValue+1)] becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if (sender==self.doneBarButton)
    {
        [self.activeTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

The weirdest thing is that if I force the textfield to resignFirstResponder by some action that just does that, the 'previous' textfield suddenly becomesFirstResponder. Like it was being added to a list of responders and it became its turn....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And as is often the case when strange things happen, it was unrelated to becoming first responder. I was accidentally changing my activeTextfield pointer to nil in the middle of a bunch of logic by way of the textfield delegate. ^o^

Disregard!

Answer (score -2):

1) Try making your code less error prone.

instead of this

```
if(sender==self.previousBarButton&&self.activeTextFieldArrayIndex.intValue>0)
```

do this

```
if ((sender==self.previousBarButton) && (self.activeTextFieldArrayIndex.intValue>0))
```

2) use textfield.tag property and set unique tags for these text fields. and do your stuff about become/resign first reponders by using

```
(uitextfield *)field[self viewWithTag: uniqueTag];
```

Comment: Thanks but there is a lot going on that makes just using the tags impossible. This table is dynamic.

Besides, the proper textfield is indeed receiving the becomeFirstResponder message.

Comment: are you sure, only your textfield of interest is getting the becomeFR message? could it be possible that after teh proper one, another one is getting the same message too?

Comment: Well I'm watching shouldBecomeBeginEditing and it only gets called once. So I don't thing another one is getting the same message. I think the one that is firstResponder won't give it up.

Comment: so when you say "So the textfield is getting the message to becomeFirstResponder but doesn't." do you mean, you are not seeing the cursor in it? or some other textfield is still the first responder?

Comment: some other textfield is still the firstResponder. It never resigns. But when it does from some different action, the new one becomes firstResponder like it was waiting.

Comment: is it possible for you to have a property UITextField *currentFirstResponder in that class? If so, you can always [currentFirstResponder resignFR] and before making the other field first responder.

Comment: I do have an activeTextfield property but if I call that first doesn't seem to help.

Comment: And as is often the case when strange things happen, it was unrelated to becoming first responder. I was accidentally changing my activeTextfield pointer to nil in the middle of a bunch of logic by way of the textfield delegate. ^o^

Comment: Good to know adding parentheses makes my code more robust. LOL. LET’S ADD MORE PARENTHESES EVERYWHERE!